# What is the smallest functioning version of Latex to be installed on Fedora 21?

Tags: installing

Referring back to this link [Full Installation of Latex in Fedora](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199638/how-to-fully-install-latex-in-fedora), I noticed that 1 full Gigabyte is needed in my Fedora 21 system in order to install it. But, I am sure I don't need all the packages. A good example of this would be all packages other than English language which are not needed. I am just wondering if there is a much smaller version of a full Latex which would be operational and functioning without need of installing all other languages. Please let me know if I have to use a particular installation method to avoid installing unnecessary packages.

Your Help is greatly appreciated,

Comment: It is actually the `doc` and `source` and `fonts` folders that take up most of the space. If you delete those, you'd have a very small install, but have no on-system documentation and no usable fonts for pdfTeX (but could use your own `.otf` and `.ttf` fonts with XeTeX and LuaTeX, via, say, `xelatex` and `lualatex`). This would mean installing everything, then deleting the folders you don't want. The language stuff is not that big of deal in terms of size. (Note that I'm not recommending this -- what's 1GB? -- just noting that you *could* do it [carefully].)

Comment: So, what you recommending is actually install all 1 GB and then carefully get rid of things that are not needed. Right?

Comment: No, he's really recommending that you install the 1Gb and leave it as is. Compare: the cost of your time to remove things *safely* vs the cost of (less than) 1Gb.

Comment: Yes -- *if absolutely necessary*. On my version of TeX Live (2015), the largest directory is `doc/`, which is 1.9 GB, so that would clear up a lot of space. `fonts/` is next at 1.7 GB, though I don't recommend getting rid of that one. `source/` is 258MB, which is also not strictly needed. And as Brent.Longborough points out: is 1GB that crucial on your drive?

Comment: @jon and Brent. I got it. Do you recommend "yum install texlive-scheme-full" as the best command line in Fedora 21? Or do you think there is a better installation command?

Comment: I'm in the Debian ecosystem, unfortunately, so I can't really say what is good for Fedora.  It *sounds* like a reasonable command to run, but what does 'scheme' mean in this context?

Comment: I wish I could answer your question jon.

Comment: I strongly suggest to use the full install, even if this means about `4.6 GB` -- it's good to have the full bunch of packages and regular fonts on the disk instead of post-install every time something is missing

Comment: ***Do not delete the directories if you use `yum` to install.*** If you use upstream's installer and install into `/usr/local` that's one thing. If you use `dnf` (`yum` is deprecated), the relevant directories are managed by your distro's package manager and you should not add or remove things manually. Apart from anything else, the directories will reappear periodically when you update the system and relevant packages are updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you install vanilla texlive (e.g. from https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) you can de-select things like documentation and languages you don't need. At the bottom you will always see the required size for your selection:

[image]

[image]